# 2 minimum in Python

Tags: python, list, numbers

I have a program that asks me for 5 numbers and then prints the minimum. But now, I need a program that writes the minimum and the second minimum.

```py
train=[]
min=100
for i in range(5):
    train.append(int(input("Enter a number")))
for carriage in train:
    if min>carriage:
        min=carriage
print("Minimum is ",min)
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Well, you first. What thoughts do you have on solving this problem?

Comment: I don't know. I just need help

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should avoid using `min` as a variable name. `min` is the name of a built in function, so you're shadowing that, which might cause strange things to happen.

Comment: Plus, of course, that the `min()` built-in function was the one you were looking for to solve your previous problem.

Comment: So how should it look right?

Comment: You could sort the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
train=[]
min1 = 100 #only 100, u sure?
min2 = 100
for i in range(5):
    train.append(int(input("Enter a number")))
for carriage in train:
    if min2 > carriage:
        min2 = carriage
        if min2 < min1: 
            min1, min2 = min2, min1
print("Minimum is ", min1, min2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum code version is to sort the list and slice off the first two items:

```py
train = []

for i in range(5):
    train.append(int(input("Enter a number")))

train.sort()
print(train[:2])
```